# Choropleth Maps generated from folium - 'Type' KeyError

Tags: folium, keyerror, choropleth

I am trying to generate a Choropleth Map with Folium, I keep on getting a 'Type' KeyError when it gets to the geo_data line.  Below is my following code:

```
url = ('https://github.com/camstark/calgis')
state_geo = f'{url}/ward-boundaries-simple.json'

# Calgary latitude and longitude values
latitude = 51.0534234
longitude = -114.0625892

# let Folium determine the scale.
yyc_map = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=12)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name="choropleth",
    data=df_demo,
    columns=['NAME','Number of Residents Age 25 to 54'],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Target Demographic Count in Calgary",
).add_to(yyc_map)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(yyc_map)

yyc_map
```

The data = df_demo line should be fine, I formatted my demographic data properly.  So my main question is there anything I could do to fix this coding wise or is it just a problem with the JSON file itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error occurs since `state_geo` points to invalid url: `https://github.com/camstark/calgis/ward-boundaries-simple.json`

The valid url could be constructed like this instead:

```
url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camstark/calgis')
state_geo = f'{url}/gh-pages/ward-boundaries-simple.json'
```

And there is one more issue with the provided example, given GeoJSON structure `key_on` needs to be set, for instance, to `feature.properties.ward_num`, otherwise folium will complain with error:

```
ValueError: key_on `'id'` not found in GeoJSON.
```